# how to keep vertical scroll bar aligned to right side of the page with respect to horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my web page I have a table which is larger than my page length. So I have applied horizontal scrollbar also i have vertical scroll bar for the same but the problem is it is aligned to end of the table. So user can't see that scroll bar on first view. If user scrolls horizontally to end of the table then only he can see there is a vertical scroll. Is there any way tokeep vertical scroll aligned to right side of the page ?

Comment: Please share the code you have implemented so far to make it easier to analyze your problem. Perhaps also post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply set outer div width as 100% viewport and overflow: auto or scroll

```html
<div>
display something else on page...
</div>
<div style="width:100%;height:150px;overflow:scroll;border:1px solid red">
  <table style="width:1000px;height:500px;table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
display something else on page...
</div>
```